# Replace string anywhere in jsp

Tags: java, jsp

On my site I've got hundreds of jsps with thousands and thousands of points of data. In a majority of these points of data the encoding used is strange. It replaces some characters with string like {(!decimal_point!)}. I would like 1 central point where all of them get converted. I was thinking I could replace anywhere in the jsp/html that these strings are found with their correct characters.

The data comes from hundreds of sources. Some files, some database, some search engine, some xml files, etc... I would love to put all those sources into 1 place, but that's a long term goal. I would like to hack a solution to this today until all my sources are in one or two central places and then I could convert the data at the source instead.

Is there a way to find and replace strings in the entire jsp/html output?

Comment: This String to replace is inside a scriptlet or in the HTML?

Comment: in scriptlet, but it would be at thousands of points of data, not just one or two. Is there a way to go through all of the jstl variables and would that be slow?

For instance, perhaps ${time} has a {(!decimal_point!}), but so could ${temp}, ${date.hour}, ${price.detailedPrice.format}, and thousands of other variables.

Comment: You can write a filter that wraps the response in a custom response object.  Then perform the replace in your custom response object.

Comment: You are talking about a spring filter?

Wouldn't I need to loop through all of the model attributes and drill down into each one of them looking for the string?

Or are you talking about some way to get the html as a response object?